# why can i not make it into a list? javascript todo list

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
  const todo = [{
    task: 'Wash Plates',
    day: 'Monday'
  },{
    task: 'Clean Pc',
    day: 'Tuesday'
  }]




  todo.forEach((list, date) => {
    console.log(list.task);
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < todo.length; i++) {
    console.log(i + 1);
  }
```

Im trying to make my output be:

1. washplates
2. Clean PC

   - i am new to javascript - can someone help please. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! The second argument to `forEach`'s callback is the index. See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one loop:

```js
const todo = [{
    task: 'Wash Plates',
    day: 'Monday'
  },{
    task: 'Clean Pc',
    day: 'Tuesday'
  }]

for (var i = 0; i < todo.length; i++) {
    console.log(`${(i + 1)}. ${todo[i].task}`);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply - what does this do line do ${todo[i].task} - i understand the string $ part but what does the the array with the loop variable in do

Comment: You are iterating over the array, printing the index of each element + 1 and the task of the element at this index. `` `${(i + 1)}. ${todo[i].task}` `` is simply to concatenate everything using template literals.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
const todo = [{
task: 'Wash Plates',
day: 'Monday'}
,{
task: 'Clean Pc',
day: 'Tuesday'
}]
for (var i = 0; i < todo.length; i++) {
console.log((i + 1)+todo[i].task));
}
```

It is just adding that line under the for loop you made

Answer (score 0):

```
todo.forEach((list, index, array) => {
    console.log((index+1) + '. ' +  list.task);
  });
```

Foreach MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution using `for...in` loop:

```
const todo = [{
  task: 'Wash Plates',
  day: 'Monday'
},{
  task: 'Clean Pc',
  day: 'Tuesday'
}]

for (const idx in todo) {
  console.log(`${parseInt(idx) + 1}. ${todo[idx].task}`);
}
```

- [for...in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)
- [Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)